# change position of image overlay on the fly

Tags: linux, image, dynamic, ffmpeg, overlay

I need some help on an issue that I am having overlaying images on a live feed.
Currently, I am streaming raw data from a device, transcoding that data (i.e. `ogg`) and then re-streaming using HTTP because I need to view through an HTML page.  My problem is that I need to overlay an image on the stream where - when a particular object moves - the image overlay moves as well.

For example, if you wanted to place an 'X' over a moving object where that object may move left-to-right or top-to-bottom.  At this point, I am able to overlay the image at a fixed point using the following command:

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://[host]:[port] -i x.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' http://[host]:[post]/output.ogg

This will give me an 'X' over the object at the start but, once the object moves I need to change the position of that 'X'.

The only real requirement is that the technologies that I utilize need to be available for Linux.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Gstreamer is the ideal solution for your problem. A simple application will give you this. www.gstreamer.net